# After I modify a variable in python how can I print the original?

Tags: python, python-3.x

eg. if I have

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] 
a.pop(0)
print(a)
```

this returns `[2,3,4,5]`

but how could I print the original list? I want to print [1,2,3,4,5].
I specifically want to use the pop function because I have to use it as a part of my assignment.

Comment: Hi ! No, you can't. The a.pop(0) modifies the original list. It would ruin performance to keep the old values of a variable. 
If you don't want to modify the original list, create a copy of it and store it in a new variable, like a_original = a.copy().

Comment: If you want the original don't modify it. You can access elements by index, no need to use `pop()`. Note, right now you just throw away the element you pop out, so why the `a.pop()` call in the first place if you want the original.

Comment: If you want to see what was in the list before you modified it, make a copy of it beforehand. Or just don't alter it.

Comment: print([a.pop(0)]+a)

Answer (score 1):

Using a.pop(0) directly modifies the original list a, removing the first element. This is an in-place operation, meaning it alters the list without creating a new one. Python is designed this way for efficiency, as keeping track of previous states of a variable can be resource-intensive.

However, if your goal is to use pop but still retain the original list, you can first create a copy of the list. This way, you can apply pop to the copied list, leaving the original unaltered. Here's how you can do it:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Create a copy of the original list
a_original = a.copy()

# Use pop on the copied list
a.pop(0)
```

This should do what you want it to do. Obviously, you can change the names to your convenience. Don't forget : naming your variables well is important and the future you will thank you !

Have a good day,

Elias.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with this original list.
But a solution may be :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a.copy()
a.pop(0)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to save the original list, make a copy of it and store it in a variable.

`.pop()` takes a element from the array and returns it, modifying the array it took an element from and removing said element.

> pop([i]) Removes the item with the index i from the array and returns
> it. The optional argument defaults to -1, so that by default the last
> item is removed and returned.
> [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)